# two syntax problems with join and left-join in the same query

Tags: mysql, join, laravel, left-join

I have this code to create a collection:

```
$rank_entities_by_capacity = Entity::join('entity_capacitytypes', function($q){
     $q->on('entitys_id', '=', 'entities.id');
     $q->where('capacitytypes_id','=', '23');
 })->
leftJoin('user_attitudes', function($q){
                $q->on('entity_id', '=', 'entities.id');
                $q->where('item_type', '=', 'entity');
            })
            ->selectRaw('entities.*, SUM(user_attitudes.importance) AS importance')
            ->groupBy('entities.id')
            ->orderBy('importance', 'desc')
            ->take(6)
            ->get();
```

### First problem:

1052 Column 'entity_id' in on clause is ambiguous:

[2015-01-01 13:22:28] production.ERROR: FATAL DATABASE ERROR: 500 = SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'entity_id' in on clause is ambiguous (SQL: select entities.*, SUM(user_attitudes.importance) AS importance from `entities` inner join `entity_capacitytypes` on `entity_id` = `entities`.`id` and `capacitytypes_id` = 23 left join `user_attitudes` on `entity_id` = `entities`.`id` and `item_type` = entity group by `entities`.`id` order by `importance` desc limit 6) [] []

I traded over an hour for finding a trick to bypass the problem:
I was forced to change column name in table **entity_capacitytypes** from **entity_id** (it was causing problems) to **entitys_id** just in order to avoid this error.
Now my database names are not consistent. Any other way to avoid the error?

### Problem 2:

If I add this part to the query, and try to use a previously perfectly working variable in the **where** line

```
join('entity_capacitytypes', function($q){
     $q->on('entitys_id', '=', 'entities.id');
     $q->where('capacitytypes_id','=', $capacity);
 })->
```

I get this error:
**Undefined variable: capacity**

How make the variable work?

My solution: avoidance again.

I ould't fix join, so I used a relation defined in Capacitytype model:

```
    public function entities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Entity', 'entity_capacitytypes', 'capacitytypes_id', 'entitys_id');
}
```

and instead using join, I accessed Entity from another model

```
 $rank_entities_by_capacity = Capacitytype::find($capacity)->entities()->
leftJoin('user_attitudes', function($q){
                $q->on('entity_id', '=', 'entities.id');
                $q->where('item_type', '=', 'entity');
            })
            ->selectRaw('entities.*, SUM(user_attitudes.importance) AS importance')
            ->groupBy('entities.id')
            ->orderBy('importance', 'desc')
            ->take(6)
            ->get();
```

### To do:

make the variable work in join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem 1

To fix the "ambiguous column" problem you only need to specify the full column name including the table

`entity_capacitytypes.entity_id` instead of only `entity_id`

### Problem 2

To use a local variable like `$capacity` inside a closure (aka anonymous function) you need to inject them with `use`

```
join('entity_capacitytypes', function($q) use ($capacity){
    $q->on('entitys_id', '=', 'entities.id');
    $q->where('capacitytypes_id','=', $capacity);
})
```